# Database Backup, drop transaction logs, shrink, drop nonclustered indexs, rebuild tables Fill factor 100%, compress

Tags: database-backups, transaction-log, compression

Let me start by saying I am a developer and I am just taking database backups for bug testing/fixing.

I want to get the size of the backups I am taking down because at the moment it would be faster getting the backups posted to me than transfering them over the intranet, and the first thing I do after restoring any backups on my development system is drop and shrink the transaction logs anyway.

Is there a way using SQL Server Managment Studio 2005 to take a backup that doesn't include the transaction log, or the nonclustered index tables, and can rebuild the tables in the backup so it has a fill factor of 100%, and then compress the backup file?

Or at least is there a way I can take a backup that doesn't include the transaction log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a script working that backed up the database and changed the fill factor on the tables and dropped the indexes and created a script to recreate them when restoring them but it didn't make a lot of difference to the final size of the database after compressing, so stuck to just backing up the database and and then using 7zip to compress it.